# How to create a single element array and group them into a single array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I run the code below:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.binomial(n=1, p=0.2, size=[10])
```

I get (you may get something different because of randomness)

```
array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

How do I get the results to be in this format?

```
array([ [0], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0] ])
```

I've tried np.array. Any suggestion? I'm making a label for neural network problem.

Comment: NumPy arrays and [Python `array`s](https://docs.python.org/library/array.html#module-array) are very different things. Please always include the NumPy tag when asking about NumPy, as described in the [tag:python] tag wiki.

Comment: `np.random.binomial(n=1, p=0.2, size=[10,1])`?

Comment: Brush up on numpy array dimensions. The first has (10,) shape, the second (10,1). Practice using `reshape`.

Comment: Thanks folks! @Nick your code solved it.